# Notes app that syncs between Android and Windows

Tags: windows, android, windows-10, note-taking, synchronization

I am seeking a simple application, or two apps in combination with a way to synchronize them (e.g. via an account, Google Drive, Dropbox or OneDrive, doesn't matter if set-up is complicated as long as it works), which allows me to use sticky notes on an Android phone supporting home screen widgets synchronized with a Windows 10 PC supporting live tiles in the start menu.

So far, I have found *Evernote* and *OneNote* (available on both Android and Windows) and *EasyNotes for Keep* (a Windows store app which connects to Google Keep which is again available on Android); however, these unfortunately don't support live tiles.

Comment: Not tried any, but there are tons available in [my notes apps listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes) which sync either via some cloud storage or by other means (Cltr-F "sync" :)

Comment: Up vote this feedback to add live tile support to OneNote on the feedback hub in Windows https://aka.ms/Gg58f1

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try [gtasks pro (windows version)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/gtasks-pro/9wzdncrdrk77#)  and its android counterpart, [gtasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gtask&hl=en). It basically keeps tasks and syncs much like the applications you mentioned in question.